# Which is faster, hex encoding or base64 encoding?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, hex, base64

I want to send or store a huge binary file, which must be encoded as text.

Which would be the faster encoding method between `hex` encoding and `base64` encoding?

The data is around 40 MB or more, which is why the performance matters.

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to run some benchmark testing...

Comment: What makes you think you should encode it at all? It would be fastest if you didn't.

Comment: i want to encode it, becoz server denies sending of binary files or programs. so i have to convert it and then send it.

Comment: *If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses*** - see [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert for more background

Answer (score 20):

The time spent on the encoding itself isn't really the issue. Base64 is more complex, but the encoding will still not be a large overhead. The real issue is the time spent on transmitting the data over the network, which depends on the encoded size of the data.

- Base64 expands the size of data compared to its binary form by one third. So your 40 MB file will be about 53 MB.
- Hex encoding doubles the size of the data, so your 40 MB file will be 80 MB.

In short, Base64 wins.

Comment: Ascii85 is most efficient as far as storage size if you must store as a string https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85

Comment: When using cryptography and sending raw data over the network then I need to be able to read the binary data.  In short, Hex wins for that scenario.